# How do I create a drop down list that redirects to a link when a button is pressed in html?

Tags: html, button, drop-down-menu

I already know how to create a button and a drop down list. However, I need to have a list with a bunch of links, and when the user selects one and hits the 'Go!' button next to it, the page is redirected to that link.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<select name="myList" id="ddlMyList">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://www.ask.com">Ask</option>
</select>


<form action=ddlMyList>
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Link">
</form>
```

However, it tries to redirect to 'ddlMyList'.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the reason that your original code is redirecting to ddlMyList is because you have that string as the action of the form. When you click the 'Go to Link' button, the form is submitted. Since the action is 'ddlMyList' it's going to do a get request on ddlMyList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace  tag with  below and add javascript function to manage link redirecting.

```
<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="go(document.getElementById('ddlMyList').value)" value="Go to link"/>
</div>

<script>
   function go(href){
      window.location.replace(href);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: How do I add text to the button? +1 by the way

Comment: @aj8uppal : Do you mean the situation when you do it dynamic?In that case you can add on change event to the select list, something like onchange="document.getElementById('My_button').value = this.value" and add id attribute to the button.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need JS to do that

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/suhur/1/edit)**

```
<script>

    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var list = document.getElementById("ddlMyList");
      window.location.href = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
    };

</script>
```